# Get selfdefine data type from oracle

Tags: oracle, vba, plsql

I have package in Oracle. In it I have selfdefine data type. f.e.:

```
TYPE t_test IS RECORD(
     v_one NUMBER
   , v_two NUMBER
);
```

How can I pass this datatype to Excel VBA? f.e:

```
Dim tTest AS t_test
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'pass to'? You can declare user defined types [like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/user-defined-data-type), but I don't think you can actually use the type from Oracle. In addition, I doubt if there is a way to automatically map Oracle data to your user defined type, so you may have to fetch data as separate numbers and combine them again into the VBA type.

Comment: I mean use this Oracle type as selfdefine VBA type